# Trying to get my python program to run but I keep getting a variable assignment error. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    
    name = ''.join(user_word.lower().split())
    name = name.replace('-','') # what?
    limit = len(name)
    phrase = True

    while running:
        temp_phrase = phrase.replace(' ', '')  
        if len(temp_phrase) < limit:
            print(f"length of anagram phrase = {len(temp_phrase)}")

            find_anagram(name, dict_file)
            print("Current anagram phrase =", end = " ")
            print(phrase, file=sys.stderr)

            choice, name = process_choice(name) 
            phrase += choice + ' '

        elif len(temp_phrase) == limit:
            print("\n**FINISHED!!**\n")
            print("Anagram of name", end = " ")
            print(phrase, file=sys.stderr)
            print()
            try_again = input("\n\nWant to try again? (Press Enter or else 'n' to quit)\n")
            if try_again.lower() == 'n':
                running = False
                sys.exit()
            else:
                main()
```

after running my code I keep getting the error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'running' referenced before assignment
```

so I tried making a variable named running in my main function's argument but I got a different error so I just figure I would try to work out this first. Any clue as to how to fix it.

Side note: this problem is from the book impractical python projects (chapter 3 project 5), I copied almost every bit of code so I'm not sure how it isn't working.

Comment: Presumably you mean to set `running` to True before your loop. Otherwise how is `while running` supposed to work?

Comment: add this after `phrase=True` line. `running=True`

Comment: It's hard to misunderstand the meaning of that error message.  You have `while running:` before you've given a value to `running`.  The full error message should have even told you which line was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting a variable referenced before assignment error is because, as the error describes, you are referencing a variable before assigning any value to it.

The variable `running` is only referenced inside the while loop, not before. for this to work, you would have to add a line above your while loop assigning a value to `running`.

Consider this example:

```
def my_function():
    print(my_variable)
    my_variable = 'this is a string'

my_function()
```

In this example, I attempted to print `my_variable`. However, there was nothing assigned to it before I tried to print it. So the output is the following:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'my_variable' referenced before assignment
```

However, if I assign the variable some value before I print it like this, I get the output I am expecting.

```
def my_function():
    my_variable = 'this is a string'
    print(my_variable)

my_function()
```

Output:

```
this is a string
```

You may ask why this happens, shouldn't python be able to see that I assigned a value to it and just print that value? The answer to that question is no. To put it simply, Python is executed from top to bottom, so when there is an attempt to print `my_variable` without assigning anything to it above, the code crashes. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/internal-working-of-python/) is some info on how python code works.